# Cloned Repository Not Up to Date

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I am using PyCharm.

I cloned a bunch of remote repositories from stash.

I can clone them fine, but I noticed that when I am looking at them, they are not up to date.

I recently had them set up, but I had to start over on a new PC, so I know there are more recent tests.

But, I don't see them.

How can I bring my cloned repository up-to-date?

Comment: are you looking for `git pull`?

Comment: The more recent tests may be on a different branch, or they may have been deleted again, or you may have cloned from a different location, and there is any number of other possible reasons.  To be able to give you a useful reply, we would need a lot more specific information on what exactly you did and what exactly you noticed, otherwise it's impossible for us to answer your question.

Comment: your comment actually helped me investigate further and figure out the issue. i was cloning the master and i needed to change the branch so i found out how to clone the specific branch and for now... im all set... more questions soon though lol